# Has adp-connection-ruby gem been deleted from ADP Labs GitHub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Answer:** yes it has been!

If you wake up to this error, it may be due to the fact has adp-connection-ruby has been deleted (or made private) from the ADP Labs GH account.

Error on my (Circle)CI:

```
Fetching https://github.com/adplabs/adp-connection-ruby
ERROR: Repository not found.
```

**Solution:**
In the meantime, while ADP Labs don't restore it, you can point to https://github.com/heliocola/adpish-connection-ruby

You can try your luck with the version on Rubygems, but that version is not up to date.
There was a commit on Jan-8-2021 to remove the dependency to json gem `~> 1.8` due to a CVE.

Comment: hi, your post has already been really helpful and i've been digging your repo. I'm trying to connect to ADP (for testing, as i'm currently waiting for production credentials) and i'm getting an "unable to get local issuer certificate" error. Do you happen to know what can i do to fix this and test connecting to ADP?